# Integer as the datatype of 'Price' Column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm thinking of using INT as the datatype of the Price column of my database table. And then, when showing the price on the website, I just use a php function that formats the integer and display the commas and dots in the appropriate places. Is it wrong? Am I gonna run into problems if I do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

This is how our site handles pricing.  In the long run it will be easier to calculate the final prices, adding / subtracting int's is easier than floats or decimals (in my opinion). Another area is the locale could be changed more easily as your setting the locale specific pricing at the client instead of the database.  So yes I would go with an int or bigint if your working with larger dollar values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - but they are easily solvable. You also need to store a scaling factor to by applied to the integer, or a denominator. The scaling factors implementation is up to you (could be a list of fixed scales, could be power of 10, could be powers of 7.36 (ugg))

So for example you store 1 as the price and -2 as the scale then you can do 1 x 10^-2 aka 1 * 0.01 = 0.01

We use scaling all the time to transmit real time market data over the wire to give a compression factor. Much cheaper to send 1 and know the scale is 10^6, rather that a 1,000,000